# Como limitar um input do tipo Number para apenas 3 caracteres pelo Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou com um problema de uma variável do tipo integer, pois o maxlength="" só funciona com string e preciso barrar, mas é do tipo Number. Acho que precisa do javascript, se alguém souber a solução agradeceria.

1
Estou com um problema de uma variável do tipo integer, pois o maxlength="" só funciona com string e preciso barrar, mas é do tipo Number. Acho que precisa do javascript, se alguém souber a solução agradeceria.

Atualização: já estou usando max="999" e min="0", porém não funcionar.

Eu encontrei a seguinte solução se fosse com javasctipt;

```
function somenteNumeros(e) {
    var charCode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    // charCode 8 = backspace   
    // charCode 9 = tab
   if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9) {
       // charCode 48 equivale a 0   
       // charCode 57 equivale a 9
       var max = 3;
       var num = document.getElementById('num');           

       if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)||(num.value.length >= max)) {
          return false;
       }

    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="num" placeholder="Digite o numero" type="number" onkeypress="return somenteNumeros(event)" required>
```

Mas eu estou usando Angular e preciso de uma solução que o trecho de código fosse em typescript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está desenvolvendo com **Angular** deveria já saber como transpor um código `Vanila` para `Typescript`, fiz um exemplo aqui pra você que pode ser testado no [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-number?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

**TS:**

```
somenteNumeros(e: any) {
  let charCode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  // charCode 8 = backspace   
  // charCode 9 = tab

  if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9) {
    // charCode 48 equivale a 0   
    // charCode 57 equivale a 9
    let max = 3;    

    if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)||(e.target.value.length >= max)) return false;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="num"  placeholder="Digite o numero" type="number" (keypress)="somenteNumeros($event)" required>
```